# start-all.cmd gives error "til.SysInfoWindows: Expected split length of sysInfo to be 11. Got 7" in windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I have done hadoop 2.8.1 setup in windows without cygwin. I have followed all steps mentioned in http://toodey.com/2015/08/10/hadoop-installation-on-windows-without-cygwin-in-10-mints.

But when I start hadoop by start-all.cmd, I am getting this error in yarn nodemanager cmd

11:21 WARN util.SysInfoWindows: Expected split length of sysInfo to be 11. Got 7
17/11/12 20:11:24 WARN util.SysInfoWindows: Expected split length of sysInfo to be 11. Got 7
17/11/12 20:11:27 WARN util.SysInfoWindows: Expected split length of sysInfo to be 11. Got 7
17/11/12 20:11:30 WARN util.SysInfoWindows: Expected split length of sysInfo to be 11. Got 7
17/11/12 20:11:33 WARN util.SysInfoWindows: Expected split length of sysInfo to be 11. Got 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a warning. Hadoop server is getting started even after this warning. Just use jps command to check if hadoop services are started or not.